# Getting day of week from macro variable

Tags: sas

I have a macro variable formatted as a date and am trying to use the weekday function to obtain the day of the week that corresponds to the value of my macro variable.

I'm receiving an error stating, "Argument 1 to function weekday referenced by the %sysfunc macro function is not a number".

Posted my code below. What am I doing wrong? TIA.

```
/*Assign program run date*/
%Let RefDate = %unquote(%str(%')%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-0),mmddyy8.)%str(%'));

%let run_day2 = %sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(compress(&refdate., "'")), mmddyy8.), date9.);
%put &run_day2.;

*Assign today;
%let current_day = %sysfunc(weekday(&run_day2));
%put Current day of week: &current_day;
```

Comment: Don't format RUN_DAY2 using the DATE9 format if you just want to use it later in the call to the WEEKDAY() function.  You only need to format the value if you want to use in something human's need to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler version:

```
%let current_day = %sysfunc(today(), weekday.);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reeza's answer is correct, but just to explain the problem in your code:

```
%Let RefDate = %unquote(%str(%')%sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(today()),-0),mmddyy8.)%str(%'));

%let run_day2 = %sysfunc(inputn(%sysfunc(compress(&refdate., "'")), mmddyy8.), date9.);
%put &run_day2.;
```

Shows &rund_day2 resolves to: 06JUN2023.  And 06JUN2023 is not a number, which is causing your error.  But "06JUN2023"d is a number, because it is a SAS date literal.  So you could change the second part of your code to:

```
*Assign today;
%let current_day = %sysfunc(weekday("&run_day2"d));  *Added quote marks and d suffix;
%put Current day of week: &current_day;
```

and the code would work. But of course Reeza's answer is a much easier and clearer way to get what you want.